# How to I have several haml lines appear on the same line?

Tags: ruby, haml

I have the following haml:

```
  9       %strong Asked by:   
 10       = link_to @user.full_name, user_path(@user)     
 11       .small= "(#{@question.created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y")})"
```

This currently puts the link and the date on separate lines, when it should look like "link (date)" and date has a class span of small.....

Comment: put your generated html code here

Comment: The default in haml is to use divs when using something like `.small` so the block layout will make it appear on a new line (unless you've explicitly changed the layout style of divs in the `small` class to be inline). You could try `%span.small` instead of just `.small`.

Comment: @matt your comment sounds like a valid answer to me.

Comment: @rubii yeah, it was going to be "try a span" but it expanded more than I expected. I'll expand it into a full blown answer a bit later when I get a bit of time.

Comment: will it all show up on the same line then....?  what if I wanted it all physically on the same line of code in haml?

Comment: I wonder too: is `%strong Asked by: %small hello` valid HAML syntax (outputting 2 div's on the same "physical text line").

Comment: @Zabba No, it is not. You can do `%strong Asked by: <small>hello</small>` to inline HTML.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code will generate something like this html:

```html
<strong>Asked by:</strong>
<a href="userpath">User name</a>
<div class='small'>April 26, 2011</div>
```

When you use something like `.small` (i.e. use the dot without specifying the element type) haml creates an [implicit `div`](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#implicit_div_elements). Since `div` elements are by default [block level elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-boxes) the date will be in a new block and so will appear on a new line. In order to get it to appear on the same line, you'll need an [inline level element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-boxes).

You could change the css for the "small" class to explicitly make it display inline, but html already provides an inline version of the `div` - the `span`, so you can change the last line from

```
.small= "(#{@question.created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y")})"
```

to

```
%span.small= "(#{@question.created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y")})"
```

which will give you

```html
<strong>Asked by:</strong>
<a href="userpath">User name</a>
<span class='small'>April 26, 2011</span>
```

which are all inline elements, so will appear as one line.

As for having it all on the same line in the haml, I don't think that's possible with plain haml syntax. Haml uses the indentation and whitespace in order to determine what to do, and having just one line means there's no indentation.

The [haml FAQ](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.FAQ.html#q-punctuation) says:

> Expressing the structure of a document and expressing inline formatting are two very different problems. Haml is mostly designed for structure, so the best way to deal with formatting is to leave it to other languages that are designed for it.

You seem to be at the edge of what haml is intended for. You could write your html directly if you really wanted it all on one line:

```html
<strong>Asked by:</strong> #{link_to @user.full_name, user_path(@user)} <span class="small">(#{@question.created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y")})</span>
```

or perhaps you could create a helper that will generate the block for you.

Answer (score 3):

To make it show up on the same line in the browser, use `%span.small`, as in the comment above.

To make it all on one line in the HTML output, you will need to use the [whitespace removal](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#whitespace_removal__and_) syntax in Haml. Please understand that newlines in the HTML output do not effect the arrangement of text in the browser.